# Convert these time parameters to epoch time

Tags: javascript, node.js, date, time, epoch

I have the following values;

```
//date is 14-Dec-2016
let day = 14; 
let month = 12;
let year = 2016;    
let TimezoneOffset = -480; //Timezone is GMT+0800 (Malay Peninsula Standard Time)
let time = 19:34; //in HHMM format
```

Based on these 5 variables, I would like to get the epoch time in javascript.

I am using node.js v6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a date using the values, apply the timezone offset, then just get the time value:

```js
var day = 14; 
var month = 12;
var year = 2016;    
var timezoneOffset = -480; //Timezone is GMT+0800 (Malay Peninsula Standard Time)
var time = '19:34'; //in HHMM format

// Create date using UTC methods but local values
var date = new Date(Date.UTC(year, month - 1, day, time.split(':')[0], time.split(':')[1]));

// Apply timezone offset to set to UTC time
date.setMinutes(date.getMinutes() + timezoneOffset);
var timeValue = date.getTime();

// milliseconds since 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z
console.log(timeValue);

// Check UTC date and time value
console.log(new Date(timeValue).toUTCString());
```

Note that variables starting with a capital letter are, by convention, reserved for constructors. And a time like "19:34" must be a string, not a number.